# errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" but check everything I know

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, database-migration

## The problem

When running migration, the last table end up with the error in the title.

My database is a local MySQL.

## The error

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
>   1005 Can't create table `shopping_list_develop`.`#sql-1698_2b` (errno:
>   150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table
>   `products` add constraint `products_shopping_list_id_foreign` foreign
>   key (`shopping_list_id`) references `shopping_lists` (`id`) on delete
>   set null on update cascade)

## Already tried

This is what I check:

- The parent table (`shopping_lists`) is created before the child table (`products`).
- The foreign key `shopping_list_id` is of the same type of the column it references.
- The two tables, `shopping_lists` and `products` have the same DB Engine (InnoDB).

I've read other answers but can't find a solution.

## Migrations

### 2019_05_13_192170_create_shopping_lists_table.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class CreateShoppingListsTable extends Migration {

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('shopping_lists', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name')->nullable()->default(Carbon::now()->toDateString());
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
                        ->onDelete('cascade')
                        ->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('shopping_lists', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign(['user_id']);
        });
        Schema::dropIfExist('shopping_lists');
    }
}
```

### 2019_05_13_192700_create_products_table.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class CreateProductsTable extends Migration {

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('brand')->nullable()->default(null);
            $table->float('price', 6,2)->nullable()->default(null);
            $table->string('note')->nullable()->default(null);
            $table->string('salable_type');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('salable_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('shopping_list_id');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('shopping_list_id')->references('id')->on('shopping_lists')
                        ->onDelete('set null')
                        ->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('products', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign(['shopping_list_id']);
        });

        Schema::dropIfExist('products');
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help and ask me any extra info if you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `2019_05_13_192700_create_products_table.php` migration, onDelete you are setting the value to null.

```php
$table->foreign('shopping_list_id')->references('id')->on('shopping_lists')
                        ->onDelete('set null')
                        ->onUpdate('cascade');
```

But the column you have declared is not nullable

```php
$table->unsignedBigInteger('shopping_list_id');
```

Try making that column nullable by doing the following instead:

```php
$table->unsignedBigInteger('shopping_list_id')->nullable();
```